# In a statistics paper, how to know which parameterization of a given distribution is being used?

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, parameterization

Let's say I'm reading a paper, and the authors write $\alpha \sim \text{gamma}(a, b)$. How do I know which parameterization of the gamma distribution they are using? Is there a convention or must one try to infer from context?

Comment: if they never write it down explicitly, then I you have to infer  itfrom context. But if they have a special case where they say: "In the case of the gamma parameters being such and such, we obtain an exponentially distributed rv with whatever", then it's not so bad.

Comment: The mean is the product of those under one parameterisation and their ratio otherwise. You should see information on the mean stated or implied somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

There might be some conventions, but they would vary between fields ... otherwise:

> if they never write it down explicitly, then I you have to infer it
> from context. But if they have a special case where they say: "In the
> case of the gamma parameters being such and such, we obtain an
> exponentially distributed rv with whatever", then it's not so bad.

– mlofton

(and also for the gamma)

> The mean is the product of those under one parameterisation and their
> ratio otherwise. You should see information on the mean stated or
> implied somewhere.

– Nick Cox

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to tell from the dimension of the second parameter whether it is a scale or a rate.